# Delete a matrix contained in another

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices,

```
> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    2    3
 [2,]    6    1    2    3    2
 [3,]    8    1    1    3    2
 [4,]    3    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    7    2    1    2    2
 [6,]    4    2    2    2    1
 [7,]    5    2    2    3    2
 [8,]    2    2    1    2    3
 [9,]    9    1    1    3    3
```

and

```
> B
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    7    2    1    2    2
 [2,]    4    2    2    2    1
 [3,]    5    2    2    3    2
```

Matrix B is contained in A (rows 5,6,7 of A). I'm trying to write a code that delete the rows of B from A, i.e. producing a matrix like that:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    2    3
 [2,]    6    1    2    3    2
 [3,]    8    1    1    3    2
 [4,]    3    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    2    2    1    2    3
 [6,]    9    1    1    3    3
```

Comment: Do `A` and `B` always have the same number of columns?

Comment: Please provide A and B in your question. Copy the output of `dput(A)`, or the code that generated these matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `A` and `B` have the same number of columns and there is only a single match of `B` within `A`,

```
aux <- function(m) paste0(c(t(m)), collapse = "")
A[-1:-nrow(B) - (gregexpr(aux(B), aux(A))[[1]] - 1)[1] / (2 * ncol(A)), ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    2    3
# [2,]    6    1    2    3    2
# [3,]    8    1    1    3    2
# [4,]    3    1    1    1    1
# [5,]    2    2    1    2    3
# [6,]    9    1    1    3    3
```

Here `aux` converts a matrix into a string, e.g.,

```
aux(B)
# [1] "7,2,1,2,2,4,2,2,2,1,5,2,2,3,2"
```

and `gregexpr(aux(B), aux(A))` finds `B` in `A`. The rest transforms the identified position of `aux(B)` in `aux(A)` into the rows of `A` to be removed.

That is, this removes matrix `B` from `A` as a whole. A problem would arise if `B` started, say, in the middle of some row of `A`.

Comment: Nice! You could add a condition that checks if the position is divisible by ncol.

Comment: Right, but hopefully there is no need for that, in the OP's case. Another thing to check would be if there are multiple matches.

Comment: Had some fun with you idea, over in my answer. Hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use anti_join from dplyr:

```
require(dplyr) 
as.matrix(anti_join(as.data.frame (A), as.data.frame (B)))
```

This assumes that you want to remove individual lines that appear in B from A. It won't work if you're looking to remove instances of the entire B matrix only.

===

Let's try another option, based on Julius's excellent solution (if you choose to go with this, please accept Julius's solution rather than this one - I'm just trying to see if I can improve on it):

First, let's create a more complex example:

```
A<-structure(c(1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 5, 2, 9, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1
), .Dim = c(16L, 5L))
```

This matrix has two full instances of B, and one additional instance of B that starts in the middle of line 13 and ends in the middle of line 16:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    2    3
 [2,]    6    1    2    3    2
 [3,]    8    1    1    3    2
 [4,]    3    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    7    2    1    2    2
 [6,]    4    2    2    2    1
 [7,]    5    2    2    3    2
 [8,]    2    2    1    2    3
 [9,]    9    1    1    3    3
[10,]    7    2    1    2    2
[11,]    4    2    2    2    1
[12,]    5    2    2    3    2
[13,]    1    1    7    2    1
[14,]    2    2    4    2    2
[15,]    2    1    5    2    2
[16,]    3    2    1    1    1
```

Now let's try to modify Julius's solution, so that both "real" instances of B are removed but not the "accidental" instance that occurs mid-line:

```
aux <- function(m) paste0(c(t(m)), collapse = "") # Julius's original aux function
locsaux<-gregexpr(aux(B),aux(A))[[1]] #obtaining the locations of instances of B within A
locations<-((locsaux[(locsaux-1)%%ncol(A)==0]-1)/ncol(A))+1 # first, making sure the locations occur at the start of a line, then translating them to row number in A
A[-unlist(sapply(locations, function(x) seq(x,x+nrow(B)-1),simplify=FALSE)),] # removing the rows identified in previous lines plus the subsequent n-1 rows, where n is the number of rows in B
```

Result:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    2    3
 [2,]    6    1    2    3    2
 [3,]    8    1    1    3    2
 [4,]    3    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    2    2    1    2    3
 [6,]    9    1    1    3    3
 [7,]    1    1    7    2    1
 [8,]    2    2    4    2    2
 [9,]    2    1    5    2    2
[10,]    3    2    1    1    1
```

Success!